# Asp.net Dynamic link Button not raising event

Tags: asp.net, event-handling

I have a tabular data, in which at last column of every row a dynamic link button is added.

```
LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
link.Text = "Edit";
link.ID = dt.Rows[dt.Rows.IndexOf(dtRow)][0].ToString() + "|" + dt.Rows[dt.Rows.IndexOf(dtRow)][1].ToString();
link.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.AutoID;
cell.Controls.Add(link);
link.Click += new EventHandler(EditClicked);
```

The edit link is shown and on click it does the post back also But the event `EditClicked` is not fired at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're dynamically creating your LinkButton and not **recreating** it again when your page is loaded.

If you dynamically create a control and then at postback, you don't create it again (in the `Page_Load` or preferably in the `Page_Init`) the event will not be fired.

One way to solve this is by using a hidden field:
When you dynamically create the linkbuttons, set a special value to a hidden field.
Then, in the `Page_Load` (in the `if (IsPostback)` ) check the hidden field, and if it has the special value - recreate all those controls again.

Comment: Oh! I had the load on page_Prerender. Thanks for you help